Any problem passing a Salesforce security review if LWCs are using GraphQL?
GraphQL queries can be made from LWCs as below (from a GraphQL document Make Your Variables Reactive):
  @wire(graphql, {
    query: gql`
      query bigAccounts($minAmount: Currency) {
        uiapi {
          query {
            Account(where: { AnnualRevenue: { gte: $minAmount } }) {
              edges {
                node {
                  Id
                  Name {
                    value
                  }
                  AnnualRevenue {
                    displayValue
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: "$variables", // Use a getter function to make the variables reactive
  })
  graphqlQueryResult({ data, errors }) {
    if (data) {
      this.records = data.uiapi.query.Account.edges.map((edge) => edge.node);
    }
    this.errors = errors;
  }

that exposes the data model to a knowledgeable person. But the record/field is secured as normal.
Does such code pass a Salesforce security review?

To be certain, this question really should be directed to Partner Support. That said, it would be unreasonable to assume that GraphQL is inherently insecure relative to using something like getRecord or Apex Code. After all, a knowledgeable user like you or I would know how to look at every single byte that comes across the wire, examine any variable in memory, and even fake server calls directly in the browser's Developer Console. This is why it is vital that developers use the appropriate security functions (e.g. Security.stripInaccessible), and administrators use the appropriate security configurations (e.g. Profiles, Permission Sets, Sharing Rules) to prevent unauthorized data leaks or database modifications.
